# ReferenceError: Cannot access 'T' before initialization after angular production build

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

When I run my angular application v15 in live development, everything works as expected. But when I run the serve in production or build the code an run it in a docker container, it throws me an error:

```
402.js:1 Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: Cannot access 'T' before initialization
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'T' before initialization
    at Object.e (pdf-create.service.ts:30:15)
    at 6635 (pdf-create.service.ts:32:39)
    at r (bootstrap:19:1)
    at 8337 (402.js:1:144)
    at r (bootstrap:19:1)
    at 3961 (input.component.html:77:24)
    at r (bootstrap:19:1)
    at 6582 (pdf-create.service.ts:30:15)
    at r (bootstrap:19:1)
    at 4059 (pdf-delegate-popup.component.html:26:44)
```

I generated the maps so I can see the point where it was thrown. The line in pdf-create is the provided in line:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class PdfCreateService extends PdfHandling {
```

I get no error in my command line and also in a browser without any cache.

Can it be a complication with the optimization part that is done for the production build?

Comment: Maybe it's caused by optimization for production build affecting code execution order, and could be leading to a reference to variable 'T' before initialization. Hard to say. Maybe modify optimization options or check code referencing 'T' to ensure it's being initialized?

Comment: @Harlin setting "optimization": false, in the config does not produce the error (at least it runs), so it get very difficult to found out what T is....